# Using sed to replace text with slashes in crontab files

Tags: linux, bash, sed, redhat

I'm trying to replace an entry in Crontab (RedHat) with sign #.
I tried sed command like this

```
sed -i 's|35 15 * * * /tmp/vii/test.sh >/dev/null 2>&1|#|g' /var/spool/cron/root
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: editing crontab with `sed` seems an horrible idea to me. It's way better to edit manually to see if any errors occur

Comment: Please don't do this. Use `crontab -e`.

Comment: Well... I'm using BladeLogic to edit this entry and there is no option to do it manually. I have to do it on 1000 servers...

Comment: @fedorqui I often use `crontab -l | sed '/^[^#]*myToolTest/s/^/# /' | crontab` and  `crontab -l | sed '/myToolTest/s/^# //' | crontab` for activating, de-activating some cron jobs (mostyl while debugging).

Comment: @fedorqui or line number based: `sed $NumLine'{ s/^# //;t;s/^/# /;: }'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Server file edition is a bad practice!

Don't try to edit crontab files directly, use crontab tools instead!!

#### Simple `sed` way

You could use:

```
crontab -l
```

to dump actual crontab list.

```
crontab -l | sed '/vii.test.sh/s/^/# /'
```

... or more finely:

```
crontab -l | sed '/^35 \+15.*vii.test.sh/s/^/# /'
```

to pre-edit crontab list and see on terminal `sed` command result

Then:

```
crontab -l | sed '/vii.test.sh/s/^/# /' | crontab
```

to replace actual crontab list, once everything are ok.

**But warn!**

```
wrong Command | crontab
```

will erase completely your crontab list!!

#### Scripted, line number based method

There is a little [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) script:

```
#!/bin/sh

SED=`which sed`
CAT=`which cat`
CRONTAB=`which crontab`

lines=`$CRONTAB -l | wc -l`

$CRONTAB -l |
    $CAT -n

read -p 'Switch comment on line: ' line

if [ -n "$line" ] && [ $line -ge 1 ] && [ $lines -ge $line ]; then

    $CRONTAB -l |
    $SED $line'{ s/^# //;t;s/^/# /;: }'

    read -p 'Apply this? (y/[n])' apply
    [ "$apply" = "y" ] &&
    $CRONTAB -l |
        $SED $line'{ s/^# //;t;s/^/# /;: }' |
        $CRONTAB

fi
```

May produce:

```
     1  # For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
     2  #
     3  # m h  dom mon dow   command
     4  00  4    *   *   *   /path/to/another/command
     5  35 15 * * * /tmp/vii/test.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
Switch comment on line:
```

From there, if you hit `5` (followed by return):

```
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
00  4    *   *   *   /path/to/another/command
# 35 15 * * * /tmp/vii/test.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
Apply this? (y/[n])n
```

And you could press `y` if you're ok.

#### For [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) users:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t cronTab < <(crontab -l)

paste <(seq 1 ${#cronTab[@]}) <(printf "%s\n" "${cronTab[@]}")

read -p "Switch comment on line: (1-${#cronTab[@]}) " line

(( (line>0) && (${#cronTab[@]}>=line) )) && { 

    [ "${cronTab[line-1]:0:1}" = "#" ] &&
    cronTab[line-1]="${cronTab[line-1]:2}" ||
    cronTab[line-1]="# ${cronTab[line-1]}"

    printf "%s\n" "${cronTab[@]}"
    read -p 'Apply this? (y/[n])' apply

    [ "$apply" = "y" ] &&
    printf "%s\n" "${cronTab[@]}" |
        crontab
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work still. It seems that sed doesn't see the spaces in that entry. It works when I use 35 only instead all entry but it's very dangerous to do this.... I just want to comment that entry because is not necessary in Cron anymore.

Comment: @mila002 Your *space* (between 35 and 15) is probably a *tabulation*.  you could try: `35[\t ]15` maybe.

Comment: @mila002 You could have more than one space: `/^35 \+15.*vii...` or  `/^35  *15...`  (note: there is two space before star!) ... (answer edited!)

Comment: @mila002 Have a look on my last comment : Try: `/^[^#]*vii.test.sh/s/^/# /` to search for ***lines not commented, who contain `vii.test.sh`, where each dot could be any characters, like a slash...***

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something like this to replace slashes and spaces.

```
crontab -l > cron_backup.txt ; cp cron_backup.txt tmp_cron.txt;sed -i 's|tee\ -a\ /prod/bin|tee\ -a\ /var/log|g' tmp_cron.txt;crontab tmp_cron.txt
```